# include or exclude specific folder from Directory.GetDirectories()

Tags: vb.net

how do i include or exclude specific folder from `Directory.GetDirectories()` function

e.g.  i have 4 folder at `c:\test1`

1. aa
2. ab
3. ac
4. ad

how do i include only folder `aa` and `ac` from getting `Directory.GetDirectories()` or exclude `ab` and `ad`

```
rootfolder = "c:\test1"
Dim root As String() = Directory.GetDirectories(rootfolder)
```

Comment: `GetDirectories()` gets all the directories. If you want to filter them, you can filter them yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try checking the names of array elements.simply like

```
        Dim rootfolder As String
        rootfolder = "c:\test1"
        Dim root As String() = Directory.GetDirectories(rootfolder)
        Dim rootlist As New List(Of String)
        For Each c In root
            If  Path.GetFileName(c) = "aa" Or  Path.GetFileName(c) = "ac" Then  '''' c<>"ab" or c<>"ad"
                rootlist.Add(c)
            End If
        Next
        Dim root1 As String() = rootlist.ToArray()
```

Glad if it helps you.

Comment: it fails. it needs to define full path in `c= "C:\\test\aa"'`

Comment: is there a way to compare by directory name instead of full path

Comment: sorry i have updated the code to check for name..pls check